# Specifics regarding Python, Tweepy, and config parser

Tags: python, windows, executable, py2exe, tweepy

Alright, so basically what I'm trying to accomplish, is inputting twitter API values into an an EXE that was made from a python script. I've been trying to figure out how to input the strings AFTER the executable is made. So that I don't need to edit and modify the code EVERY time before making it into a standalone.

When using twitter's API you need to have access to four very specific strings to use to push and call from the API. I need to find a way to be able to insert those strings AFTER the script is converted into a windows executable. I've searched and searched to no avail. Any help would be IMMENSELY appreciated.

I've tried to use the python configparser. Maybe I'm understanding it wrong, I don't know. This is what I have so far.

Here is the ini

```
[Tweepy Keys]
consumer_key : (THE VALUE)
consumer_secret : (THE VALUE)
access_token : (THE VALUE)
access_token_secret : (THE VALUE)
```

Now i just need the main script to insert the values FROM the config into the script itself.

I've imported the configparser into it, but I'm not quite sure I'm setting it up correctly to put the values in the right location.

Comment: How about using a configuration file?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/configparser.html

Comment: It's amazing how something so ridiculously simple flies over our heads when we are looking in one direction. Thanks. Pretty sure using a config is going to answer every question I've had. It's kind of annoying how I didn't even think of it.

Comment: Now i just need the main script to insert the values FROM the config into the script itself.

I've imported the configparser into it, but I'm not quite sure I'm setting it up correctly to put the values in the right location.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it came down to syntax why everything wasn't working. Due to running on on Python3 everything was lowercase.

P2 = ConfigParser
P3 = configparser

Just had to fix a few things. Thanks guys.